# Log4j2 Delete on Rollover is not working as expected, in Pingfederate

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In Pingfederate, which internally uses log4j2 to log events. I am trying to rollover and delete older logs. While rollover functionality works, and the log is rolled over, but the deletion functionality doesn't seem to work. What do i don't understand ? Kindly explain and help me fix this.

Also, I am trying to log log4j2 itself, but for some reason it is not getting logged in the console logs.

Thanks a bunch.
If you need more information, kindly comment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
<Appenders>

    <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>

    <!-- Main log : A size based file rolling appender -->
    <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="${sys:pf.log.dir}/server_${sys:pf.ip}.log" filePattern="${sys:pf.log.dir}/server_${sys:pf.ip}.log.%i" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d %X{trackingid} %-5p [%c] %enc{%m}%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10000 KB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>

    <!-- Security Audit log : A time/date based rolling appender -->
    <RollingFile name="SecurityAudit2File" fileName="${sys:pf.log.dir}/audit_${sys:pf.ip}.log" filePattern="${sys:pf.log.dir}/audit_${sys:pf.ip}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm}.log" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
        </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
      <Delete basePath="${sys:pf.log.dir}" maxDepth="1">
        <IfFileName glob="audit*.log" />
        <IfLastModified age="2m" />
      </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>

    <!-- Admin Audit log : A time/date based rolling appender -->
    <!--
    <RollingFile name="AdminAudit" fileName="${sys:pf.log.dir}/admin.log" filePattern="${sys:pf.log.dir}/admin.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d|%X{user}|%X{roles}|%X{event}|%m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    -->

    <!-- Admin API Audit log : A time/date based rolling appender -->
    <!--
    <RollingFile name="AdminApiAudit" fileName="${sys:pf.log.dir}/admin-api.log" filePattern="${sys:pf.log.dir}/admin-api.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d|%X{api.user}|%X{api.authtype}|%X{api.clientip}|%X{api.httpmethod}|%X{api.url}|%X{api.status}%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    -->

    <!-- Runtime API Audit log : A time/date based rolling appender -->
    <RollingFile name="RuntimeApiAudit" fileName="${sys:pf.log.dir}/runtime-api.log" filePattern="${sys:pf.log.dir}/runtime-api.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d|%enc{%X{api.user}}|%X{api.authtype}|%X{api.clientip}|%X{api.httpmethod}|%X{api.url}|%X{api.status}%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Logger name="httpclient.wire.content" level="WARN" />

    <!-- Adjust the priority value to DEBUG to get additional logging to help troubleshoot XML Signature problems -->
    <Logger name="org.sourceid.common.dsig" level="WARN" />

    <!-- set to DEBUG to see inbound and outbound protocol messages -->
    <Logger name="org.sourceid.saml20.bindings.LoggingInterceptor" level="WARN"/>
    <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="WARN" />
    <Logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio" level="WARN" />
<Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</Logger>

    <Logger name="org.sourceid.websso.profiles.sp.SpAuditLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SecurityAudit2File" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.sourceid.websso.profiles.idp.IdpAuditLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SecurityAudit2File" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.sourceid.websso.profiles.idp.AsAuditLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SecurityAudit2File" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.sourceid.wstrust.log.STSAuditLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SecurityAudit2File" />
    </Logger>

    <!--
    <Logger name="AuditLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="AdminAudit" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="AdminApiAuditLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false" includeLocation="false">
        <appender-ref ref="AdminApiAudit" />
    </Logger>
    -->

    <Logger name="RuntimeApiAuditLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false" includeLocation="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RuntimeApiAudit" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="TRACE">
        <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: You have `<Configuration status="trace">`. This is the correct way to make Log4j2 dump its internal debug logging to the console. If you are not seeing this, it makes me wonder if Log4j2 is actually loading a different configuration file... Something that is on the classpath before this one?

Comment: I am sure it is this configuration file, as the other appenders and loggers work as specified. The stream is coming out in console but is not showing log4j2 logs.

Comment: You can also enable log4j2 internal status logging by setting system property `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE`

Comment: I think both are essentially same, but still will try and let you know Remko.

Comment: No, system prop is used _before_ config is found, so slightly different. Allows you to verify the correct configuration file is being used.